# How to execute a loop for every one hour in BASH?

Tags: bash

I have configured a cron job where at one step it need's to execute a command where it will take 10 - 14 hrs of time. If it's completed successfully then we will get this "Build of target : PASS" in main.txt file. How do I need to check "Build of target : PASS" in main.txt file for every one hour ?

```
if grep -q "Build of target : PASS" main.txt; then
echo "Passed"
else
echo "failed"
fi
```

I got stuck at how check/grep the word to for every one hour.

Comment: Setup another cronjob?

Comment: @DanielW., I mean to say in one crop job I have added many commands and code If I create any cron job it will be difficult for the client to understand. So that's why I can't create another cron job

Comment: @Akhil, cron can just start your script at its entry point. Why is that hard for a reader to understand? The script doesn't need to be _embedded inside_ the crontab, just a command that starts it.

Comment: The script as provided will do what you want. Are you asking how to make this run once per hour, or how to obtain the output from it if you run it from `cron`?

Comment: ...that said, if you want to _monitor a file until it's closed_, there are better tools. I wouldn't do any kind of periodic `grep` at all, but instead would do either a continuous tail, or would use `inotifywait` to be notified whenever whatever is writing to the file is finished and closes it. `grep` rereads the file from the beginning; it's inherently inefficient to run over and over when you only need to check newly-added lines.

Comment: (You can similar use `incron` to have your script started _whenever a file changes_, or whenever that file is closed, or otherwise on any other event that inotify can watch for).

Comment: @tripleee, the command which I have included in cron job it will execute for 10 - 14 hrs to get this word "Build of target : PASS" in main.txt file. Once I got this word then I will manually kill the process otherwise it will execute for 3 - 4 days. For this purpose only I need another loop to execute for every one hour to check this "Build of target : PASS".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run an hourly cron job with the code to perform the checking.

```sh
17 * * * * grep -q "Build of target : PASS" main.txt && fuser -k main.txt
```

`fuser -k` is just a simple way to kill whoever is writing to `main.txt` on Linux; if you know the PID or are on another platform, there will be other ways to figure out which process exactly to kill.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like

```
res=failes
for h in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
do  if grep -q "Build of target : PASS" main.txt
    then res="Passed"
         break
    else sleep 3600
    fi
do
if [[ Passed != "$res" ]] && grep -q "Build of target : PASS" main.txt
then res="Passed"
fi
echo "$res"
```

If the process runs for the full 14 hours and only finished successfully near the end, then at the *beginning* the 14th hour the `grep` will not find the PASS and will sleep, but at the *end* of the hour  the for loop will not enter a 15th iteration to test it again. This checks for last-minute successes, but checks the string first so that it won't need to `grep` again if already found.

A better way would probably be to flip that logic, since it's unlikely to have succeeded already at the beginning of the first hour -

```
res=failed
for h in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
do  sleep 3600
    if grep -q "Build of target : PASS" main.txt
    then res="Passed"
         break
    fi
done
echo "$res"
```

But be aware this guarantees a wait the first hour before it even checks.

Comment: may I know why second time you have written if loop. With the for loop we can execute right for 14 hrs at an interval of 1 hour?

Comment: Edited with explanation and alternate version.